# Xpath : how do i exclude the nodes inside the node I want?

Tags: xpath

In [this picture of an html tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1CD8.png) from the this picture of an html tree  I only want the `<div class="d">` node,but the  `<table>` node  and below is what I want to exclude from the `<div class="d">` node.

Comment: I want to excluive the <table> and nodes following it in the <div class="d"> node,any help is appreciate since i'm new to scrapy

Answer (score 2):

well you can either manually pick them one by one by doing something like this

```
tablePath = "//div[@class='d']/table"
table = response.selector.xpath(tablePath ).extract(),
para_1_Path = "//div[@class='d']/p[5]"
para_1 = response.selector.xpath(para_1_Path).extract()
```

and so on

OR you can extract all of the div `class="d"` data and trim it but this would be tricky as you say you're new to scrapy.

Comment: you can use indexing as well

Comment: sorry, the question is massed up before, which is not exactly what i really want, rewrite again, except for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xpath `count`:

```
count(preceding-sibling::table)>0
```

something like:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> s = '''
... <div class="d">
...   <p style="text-align: center">...</p>
...   <p>...</p>
...   <h2>Daydream...</h2>
...   <p>...</p>
...   <p>...</p>
...   <p>VRsat</p>
...   <table><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table>
...   <p style="text-align: center">...</p>
...   <p style="text-align: center">...</p>
...   <div id="click_div">...</div>
... </div>
... '''
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> xpath = '//div[@class="d"]/*[self::table or count(preceding-sibling::table)>0]'
>>> for x in doc.xpath(xpath): x.tag
...
'table'
'p'
'p'
'div'
```

**UPDATE**:

The OP is actually asking about the inverse from my solution above.

So, add `not`, switch to `and`, change the *count* to `=0`:

```
>>> xpath = '//div[@class="d"]/*[not(self::table) and count(preceding-sibling::table)=0]'
>>> for x in doc.xpath(xpath): x.tag
...
'p'
'p'
'h2'
'p'
'p'
'p'
```

Comment: firstly, apprecate for your help,but sorry is the description of my question is massed up before, it is NOT what i want to describe at the first, now i rewrite the question ,  i don't want the <table> node and all below of it

Comment: got it,  I really appreciate this.

Comment: Appreciation in the form of text is great; in the form of an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is better.  If the answer solves the stated question then feel free to "accept".